# What is purpose of PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior.Summarize in Acumatica?

Tags: erp, acumatica

What is purpose of PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior.Summarize in Acumatica? 
PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior.Initialize makes new value inserted, PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior.Replace replaces old value, but I can't grasp from T200 what PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior.Summarize does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in help of Acumatica at part PXDataFieldAssign.AssignBehavior Enumeration. It says that the new value is added to the value stored in the database.